# facebook javascript sdk getLoginStatus() problems

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to set up the Facebook Javascript SDK to let users log into a site via Facebook. Needless to say, I'm kind of confused by the documentation on Facebook.  My first question is, am I able to detect when a user comes to my site who is logged into Facebook and determine their Facebook ID and from there log them into my site (all without any user interaction)?  It seems like everything is working ok except for this part.  If the user clicks the Facebook login button then everything works fine and getLoginStatus() runs correctly.  But on initial page load getLoginStatus() does not seem to invoke the callback function. And I was under the impression that there shouldn't even be a Login button, instead it should be the Facebook "register" button if they are logged in to Facebook.  I've included some code below.  If anyone could give me any guidance on this I would greatly appreciate it.  Please keep in mind that I have removed my app id and my site name and replaced them with "dummy" text.

```
<!-- Load Facebook javascript SDK (This should be the first item after the opening body tag) -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script> 
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: myAppId, status: true, cookie: true,
                 xfbml: true});

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.session) {
            // logged in and connected user, someone you know
                    alert('I know you');
          } else {
            // no user session available, someone you dont know
               alert('Who are you?');
          }
            alert(response.session.uid);

        });
      };

      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';

        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
</script>
<fb:login-button show-faces="false" width="70" max-rows="1" registration-url="myRegistrationUrl" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;"></fb:login-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello as for as I have understood you want to login the user into your site based on their facebook accounts. I have done the same. First let the user login to facebook, then send its user id to your user table and then logins him into your site. for me below code works.

```
<div id="fb-root">
 <script>
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({appId: "XXXXXX",
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true});

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.session) {
        //here send the parameters to your system that logins into your system
        self.location.href="http://www.yoursite.com/login.php";
      } else {

        }
    }); 
    FB.Event.subscribe("auth.login", function(response) {
    window.location.reload();
      });
FB.Event.subscribe("auth.logout", function(response) {
    // to logout

    self.location.href="http://www.yoursite.com/logout.php";
      });
     };
   (function() {
     var e = document.createElement("script");
     e.type = "text/javascript";
     e.src = document.location.protocol +
     "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     e.async = true;
     document.getElementById("fb-root").appendChild(e);
   }());
   </script>
```

at login.php you can check their username. and log in them into your site. What i did, I send its user id that returned to me via jason as their username and send it as after md5 as password in my usertable. then i simply compare the userid in my user table in login.php and log the user in to my site. I hope it will work for you also

Comment: In login.php do you check the signature of the data coming from Facebook to make sure that it is valid and safe (i.e. it's not spoofed data)

Comment: @Robert Conn. I didnt understand your point dear. If I am getting data through access token then how can I get spoofed data?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the url very informative and worked!

http://www.permadi.com/blog/2010/11/facebook-open-graph-api-authenticating-in-iframe-applications/